# storing captured image in isolated storage without saving into camera roll of the window phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am working on windows mobile application in which I need to store a captured image from the camera in isolated storage without saving it in the camera roll.
I am able to store the captured image in the isolated storage but a copy of the captured image in also stored in the camera roll that I don't want.

Comment: I just wrote a free isolated storage dll. Very easy to use http://www.anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=47